# Get USB Disks list in Qt

Tags: linux, qt, usb

I`m Using Qt for development, and writing a program for Linux platform.
I need to find USB Disks path (for example /dev/sdb). How can I do that?

Comment: Qt provides no help here, you need to implement it using platform-specific APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://api.kde.org/frameworks-api/frameworks5-apidocs/solid/html/index.html which nicely integrates with Qt. You can also use the DBus APIs published by UDisks2: https://udisks.freedesktop.org/docs/latest/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `usbmount` package to auto mount USB pens on plug, and use `QStorageInfo` to get volume information.

Comment: unfortunately I found that `usbmount` doesn't exists in debian, you can use `udisks2` with `udev` to automount USB disks.

Answer (score -1):

df command helps with finding the mounted location.
try the below command.
**df -h**

additional info: df => Disk File system, -h => Human readable